# How to break on the entry point of a program when debug in kernel mode with windbg?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I want to debug a program in kernel mode, and I want to break on the entry point of the program like `ollydbg`. But I can't break it with `bp` because the program is not start and the symbol can't be loaded. I have found some way to do it but I think it's not so good.

1.Break on the `CreateProcess` function in kernel. But I don't know which function exactly should I break and I think there is a long way between `CreateProcess` and the entry point of the program.

2.Change the entry point of the program with `cc`. But it needs other tools and I should change the code where the byte changed back. I think it is annoying.

3.With the help of `ollydbg`. Debugging the program with `ollydbg` in a virtual machine which is debugged with windbg. I don't think that it is a good idea.

4.Use `sxe ld`. It can be found on `Listing 3.29` in `<<Advanced Windows Debugging>>`. I have tried it but I found that it only works on the first time. And I don't know what exactly should I do after the break.

5.Break on the entry function with `bu`. But I don't know what exactly I should do either. For example, how to load the symbol?

6.Use `.create`. I don't know whether it is properly or not to do what I said.

I think that it is a common use to  break on the entry point of a program when debug in kernel mode with `windbg` , and I think that there must be a good way to do that with the powerful `windbg`. What's the best way to do it?

By the way, I want to debug a program in kernel mode because I want to get the token vaule of the program. I found that the windbg can identify the token with `!token` in user mode, but I don't know how to get the value of token in user mode. It seems that I can only get the value of token in the kernel mode, right or wrong?

Comment: Security tokens live in kernel address space. This makes it possible to refer to security token using `!token <address>` in kernel debugger. In user mode tokens surface out through HANDLE's, so if you know the value of the handle, you can dump properties in user mode debugger with command `!token <handle>`.  In your case you seem to be talking about a token of the user account under which process was started, right? If so, then invoking `!token` without parameters will display the right token, assuming the thread is not impersonating. So you don't need to mess with kd at all.

Comment: I know that `!token` can show me the information of token, even there is a impersonation token. But I can only get _TS Session ID,User/Groups GUID,Primary Group,Privs,Auth ID,Impersonation level,TokenType,Is restricted token_ from `!token`. It seems that I can't get the handle of the token?

Comment: I believe that `!token` obtains a thread token by calling [OpenThreadToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379296(v=vs.85).aspx), then queries the properties of the token, and closes the handle. So the handle might not be an internal HANDLE of the process being debugged, it is internal to WinDbg itself. What other type of information you need from the token?

Comment: In fact, I want to check that when the token was changed to a impersonation token with system GUID and when it comes back in a [poc](https://code.google.com/p/google-security-research/issues/detail?id=118), but I find that I can't find the value of the token. I think I must get the value of token to check for the change.

Comment: And I need the vaule of token because it will be verified in kernel with the result of `PsReferenceImpersonationToken` or `PsReferencePrimaryToken` and I want to check for it.

Comment: Can't you use kernel debugging and user mode debugging at the same time using two instances of WinDbg? Use `.wtitle` to distinguish them. Use [AeDebug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to start the debugger automatically for the process you're interested in.

Comment: One of the ways to get the HANDLE of impersonation tokens is to set a breakpoint on [SetThreadToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379590(v=vs.85).aspx) and inspect the second parameter.

Comment: @Thomas You mean that I use a windbg to debug a virtual mathine, and start a windbg in the virtual mathine to debug the program in user mode? Are there any articles talk about it in detail?

Comment: @sevatitov I find that [SDbgExt](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=94) is easier to get the handle of token, and the example is [here](http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.platformsdk.security/2006-02/msg00041.html). But what I want to get is the real value of token from handle, which can be got from `PsReferenceImpersonationToken`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can run any exe in the target via ntsd -d  to debug it from the kernel mode debugger running in the host

assuming you are running a virtual machine **mytarget** inside **myhost**

install windbg in myhost
set symbol path for myhost viz **srv*x:\xxxx*http:\xxxxxxxxxxxx**
create a kernel connection in the host (choose the best shown below is a serial connnection)

#### X:\xxxx\windbg.exe -k com:pipe,port=\\.\pipe\debugPipe,resets=0,reconnect

install windbg in mytarget
open a shared folder z:\ pointing to the symbolcache folder in myhost
set symbolpath in mytarget pointing to the shared folder
run ntsd -d calc.exe

kd will break on $exentry of calc.exe with **Input** Prompt

as long as Input prompt is shown you are using kd like a native usermode debugger 
so if you set a bp calc!Winmain and issue g kd will break on calc.exe winmain

to get to kd session use .breakin

messy stuff but will work well once you get accustomed (ie memorizing the docs)

a sample run

```
kd> g   <-------------- kd session running in myhost

CommandLine: calc.exe 
Symbol search path is: srv*z:\
*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c90120e cc              int     3

.sympath
NOTE: The symbol path for this ntsd is relative to where
ntsd.exe is running, not where kd.exe is running.
Symbol search path is: srv*z:\
*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Expanded Symbol search path is: srv*z:\
*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

.reload /f calc.exe

lm m calc
start    end        module name
01000000 0101f000   calc       (pdb symbols)          z:\calc.pdb\3B7D84101\calc.pdb

0:000> version  <--------------------usermode session in kd via ntsd -d 
version
Windows XP Version 2600 (Service Pack 3) UP Free x86 compatible

Live user mode: <Local>

command line: 'ntsd -d calc.exe'  Debugger Process 0x3F8 

? $exentry;? calc!WinmainCrtstartup
Evaluate expression: 16852085 = 01012475
Evaluate expression: 16852085 = 01012475
```

as to your original request i am not sure what token you are interested to find

if getting the EPROCESS->Token of your exe is the only requirement you dont have to run any kd session

you can get the token of all running process in myhost with a local kernel debugging session (either using kd -kl or by using livekd from sysinternals)

here is a simple script which fetches the sid of all running process employing the above technique

```
:\>cat sid.txt
!for_each_process "r $t0 =(@@c++(((nt!_eprocess *) @#Process )->Token.Object)) &
 @@(~7); r $t1 = @@c++(((nt!_token *) @$t0 )->UserAndGroups->Sid);!sid @$t1 1; ?
? (char *)((nt!_eprocess *) @#Process )->ImageFileName "

:\>kd -kl -c "$$>a< sid.txt;q"
```

result

```
WARNING: Local kernel debugging requires booting with kernel
debugging support (/debug or bcdedit -debug on) to work optimally.

lkd> kd: Reading initial command '$$>a< sid.txt;q'
SID is: S-1-5-18 (Well Known Group: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM)
char * 0x8ac729a4
 "System"
SID is: S-1-5-18 (Well Known Group: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM)
char * 0x8a35729c
 "smss.exe"

SID is: S-1-5-20 (Well Known Group: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE)
char * 0x8a3619ac
 "svchost.exe"

SID is: S-1-5-19 (Well Known Group: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE)
char * 0x8a36ef14
 "svchost.exe"

SID is: S-1-5-21-602162358-1801674531-1417001333-1003 (User: XXXXXX\Admin)
char * 0x8a261b64
 "explorer.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the method described in the Windbg help file for debugging WinLogon. Substitute your user mode app for WinLogon:

Windbg | Help | Contents | Windows Debugging | Debugging Techniques | Specialized Debugging Techniques | Debugging WinLogon

IFEO will start your user mode app and attach ntsd.exe. From ntsd.exe, you can set a break point on image entry with `bu $exentry` then `g` to continue.

At any point that ntsd.exe is broken into your user mode process, you can issue `.breakin` command to switch to kernel mode debugging.